# What is the correct way to inject Service Fabric State Manager resources into a ICommunicationListener during initialization?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

For a ServiceFabric Stateful ReliableService:

I want to inject a IReliableQueue into a ICommunicationListener (Service Bus Topic Listener) in order to queue long running tasks for processing in the back ground.

I would preferably like to do this in the factory method overload:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
{
    var commandQueue = StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableQueue<Command>>("commandbus").Result;
    var topicListener = communicationListenerCtor(commandQueue);
    return []{new ServiceReplicaListener(context => topicListener, ...));}
}
```

Given that the StateManager only provides async access to the IReliableQueue through the GetOrAddAsync method and the factory method is sync, this approach doesn't feel correct to put it mildly..

What is the correct approach for accessing the StateManager state outside the RunAsync method?

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty close. You need the entire IReliableStateManager, not just the queue instance, because you'll need to be able to create transactions to use the queue, and that is located on IReliableStateManager.

So just change your code to:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
{
    var topicListener = communicationListenerCtor(this.StateManager);
    return []{new ServiceReplicaListener(context => topicListener, ...));}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this sample:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-getting-started/blob/master/Services/WordCount/WordCount.Service/Controllers/DefaultController.cs

I realised my design was flawed in that I injected the IReliableQueue instance rather than the IReliableStateManager. I now retrieve queue instance from the StateManager in my ICommunicationListener **instance** method rather than a constructor inject of the queue instance. I do inject the IReliableStateManager in the ICommunicationListener constructor, obviously.

Not sure if that is the best practice pattern, but that resolved my problem.

Comment: Link is now broken